# How to subscribe and receive Firebase message in pure Java (not Android)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm looking for the way I can create a receiver of Firebase Cloud Messages in Java. Things successfully work in Android, but I could not find anything to start in Java.

Official documentation does not mention Java as supported language, but I also did not find explicit statement that Java is not supported.

Here is the documentation entry points for [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), [c++](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/receive) and [WEB (Browser)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive). Where can I find something similar for Java?

Comment: [C++ is a wrapper around the iOS/Android Library](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/cpp/client).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Cloud Messaging does not support receiving messages on Java desktop apps.

The protocol was made for delivering messages to mobile (Android and iOS) devices, and then expanded for web clients. It seems unlikely this will be expanded to desktop or server apps in the (near) future, although I'd definitely recommend [filing a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/).

In the meantime, consider using another push technology, such as the [Firebase Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) or [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/).

Comment: Yes i know about Firebase and Firestore, but it may get too costly to use for messaging ... FCM is free with no limits.

Answer (score 0):

check out firebase_admin messaging module, I am able to successfully send messages to my android phone from my python server at home. I know it also allows you to subscribe to different messages. It supports Java but not aware of the technical differences